# What is the fastest bounding box prediction algorithm?

Tags: computer-vision

What is the fastest bounding box prediction algorithm without the classification?

For example, I have a flat surface with objects on top of it. I don't to need to know the type of the objects, I need only their bounding boxes. Something like pixel wise segmentation for two types of objects: ground and item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for are models for **"salient object detection"** ("dealing with locating and segmenting the most salient object or region in a scene").
The output of such a model is a map of the same size as the input image, where each pixel's value is the probability that it is part of a salient object. Using some threshold value you can locate the boundaries of the object.

You can probably find information regarding the processing requirements of different models in an article named "Salient Object Detection: A Survey" (It was just recently updated).